# Show next div when focusing on input before it , and hide it again after that (CSS3 , JavaScript, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with fields and divs next to them for each field

i need to show them with **opacity effect** (0 - 100 and 100 - 0) when focusing on field and hide them again when field is not focused

```
<!-- First -->
<tr class="tr">
    <td class="td">
        <input name="field1" type="text" class="field">
        <div class="div">Description 1</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Second -->
<tr class="tr">
    <td class="td">
        <input name="field2" type="text" class="field">
        <div class="div">Description 2</div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

So when i focus on field1 i need to show the next div with Description 1 etc...

As i don't need jquery for anything else i don't think using jquery library is the best option, so please guide with `CSS3` or `Javascript` and if there is no way then guide with `jQuery` please

i already use `document.getElementById(id) style.display=="block"` but i need to have IDs for each div and many lines of javascript and i also have the opacity or other effects problem

> ### Here is the answer after redaxmedia's guide

```
<style type="text/css">
    .divclass {
        visibility: hidden;
        zoom: 1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
        transition: all 300ms;
    }
    input.inputclass:focus + div {
        visibility: visible;
        zoom: 1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1.0;
        -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
        transition: all 300ms;
    }
</style>

<table>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="field1" type="text" class="inputclass">
        <div class="divclass">Description 1</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="field2" type="text" class="inputclass">
        <div class="divclass">Description 2</div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

the only problem is using visibility:hidden will still take place in the page its not like display:hidden

if any one has any solution for this too, please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input:focus + div {display:block}
```

if you like to have a jQuery like $.fadeIn() and $.fadeOut() effect... combine opacity, visibility and transition :-)